# Como funciona a Licença do Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, licença, gráfico

Estou desenvolvendo uma intranet para uma empresa que é minha cliente. Por enquanto é apenas um protótipo, apenas futuramente será comercializado. Nessa intranet há gráficos interativos cujos códigos são provenientes das páginas demo do Highcharts ([Como esta aqui](https://www.highcharts.com/demo)).
Para esclarecimento, não instalei o software.
Nesse caso, como funciona a licença? Preciso de alguma? Se sim, qual?
Agradeço qualquer esclarecimento.

Comment: Esse tipo de informação pode ser pego no próprio site: https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts, para utilizar o pacote free: https://shop.highsoft.com/faq#Non-Commercial-0

Comment: Se o objetivo é comercial, **sim, você precisa de uma licença**. Aqui o texto da licença free "não comercial": *"If you are a non-profit company, or use our products for personal use"*, ou seja, só para fins pessoas. No seu caso você pode usar essa versão para desenvolver o protótipo e, quando a aplicação for para produção, o cliente deve comprar uma licença. Como apontou o @MarceloBoni, na página do *Highcharts* tem as licenças, as funcionalidades e seus preços, você pode ver escolher a melhor.

Comment: O google charts pode ser usado para comercialização sem problemas? Não precisa de licença?